# Find out what fields are being updated

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQ To SQL to update a user address.
I'm trying to track what fields were updated.

The `GetChangeSet()` method just tells me I'm updating an entity, but doesn't tell me what fields.

What else do I need?

```
var item = context.Dc.Ecs_TblUserAddresses.Single(a => a.ID == updatedAddress.AddressId);

//ChangeSet tracking
item.Address1 = updatedAddress.AddressLine1;
item.Address2 = updatedAddress.AddressLine2;
item.Address3 = updatedAddress.AddressLine3;
item.City = updatedAddress.City;
item.StateID = updatedAddress.StateId;
item.Zip = updatedAddress.Zip;
item.Zip4 = updatedAddress.Zip4;
item.LastChangeUserID = request.UserMakingRequest;
item.LastChangeDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

ChangeSet set = context.Dc.GetChangeSet();

foreach (var update in set.Updates)
{
    if (update is EberlDataContext.EberlsDC.Entities.Ecs_TblUserAddress)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Did any of these answers help you?  Be sure to accept an answer by checking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ITable.GetModifiedMembers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.itable.getmodifiedmembers.aspx). It returns an array of [`ModifiedMemberInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.modifiedmemberinfo.aspx) objects, one for each modified property on the entity. [`ModifiedMemberInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.modifiedmemberinfo.aspx) contains a `CurrentValue` and `OriginalValue`, showing you exactly what has changed.  It's a very handy LINQ to SQL feature.

**Example:**

```
ModifiedMemberInfo[] modifiedMembers = context.YourTable.GetModifiedMembers(yourEntityObject);

foreach (ModifiedMemberInfo mmi in modifiedMembers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} --> {1}", mmi.OriginalValue, mmi.CurrentValue));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect Updates by observing notifications of changes. Notifications are provided through the `PropertyChanging` or `PropertyChanged` events in property setters.

E.g. you can extend your generated `Ecs_TblUserAddresses` class like this:

```
public partial class Ecs_TblUserAddresses
{
    partial void OnCreated()
    {
        this.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(User_PropertyChanged);
    }

    protected void User_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string propertyName = e.PropertyName;
        // do what you want
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to track a special property changing, you could use one of those `OnPropertyNameChanging` partial methods, e.g. (for City in your example):

```
partial void OnCityChanging(string value)
{
    // value parameter holds a new value
}
```